# javascript getting user input to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

hello im trying to get the minumum value of this array am i adding the user input to the array propperly.

```
var highestMark=0;
var gradeAwarded;
var StudentArr= [Student];
var markArr = [mark];
var Student = prompt("Enter Student Name: ", "Ross");
var mark = prompt("Enter Student Mark: ", 50);
var max;

function min (mark){
    var min = Number.Max_Value;
    for(var i = 0; i < mark.length; i++)
    if(mark[i] < min)
        min = mark[i];
    }
    return mark;

var smallest = min (mark);
document.write(smallest);
```

Comment: The typical JS way: `function min(xs){return Math.min.apply(0,xs)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's possible, but the [`prompt`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) method return a string and you can lead with this string the way you want. For sample, if you user type some values separated by a specific char `,` (for sample) you could use the `split` method and get this array, for sample:

```
var values = prompt("Eter values: ", "");
var result = values.split(',');
```

but your code looks fine, just convert the `mark[i]` to number, to sample:

```
function min (mark){
    var min = Number.Max_Value;
    for(var i = 0; i < mark.length; i++)
       if(number(mark[i]) < min)
           min = number(mark[i]); 
    return mark;
}
```

Comment: do you mean like that?